# backbone js find by collection and update

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

my model :-

```
App.bkModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

collection :-

```
App.contactsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.bkModel,
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("LibraryCollections"),

    fetch: function(options) {
        // check if localStorage for this collection exists
        // (if needed, also check whether it's empty)
        if(!localStorage.getItem("LibraryCollections")) {
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'data.json',
            }).done(function(response) {
                $.each(response.items, function(i, item) {
                    self.create(item);
                });
            });
        } else {
            return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
        }        
    }
});  

  var bkCollection = new App.contactsCollection;
```

for add and edit using addView

```
App.addView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: 'div.abPanel', 
  events: {
    'submit form#frmAddContact': 'saveBook'
  }, 
  initialize: function () {
    this.template = _.template(tpl.get('add-book'));
  }, 
  addBook: function (id) {
    var book = {},
    model = bkCollection.get(id);
    //console.log(bkCollection.get(id));
    if (id !== undefined && model !== undefined) {
        book = model.toJSON();
    }
    this.$el.html(this.template({book: book}));
  },
  getInputValues : function () {
    return {
            title : $('#title').val(), 
            author : $('#author').val(),
            quantity : $('#quantity').val(),
            price : $('#price').val(),
            description : $('#description').val(),
            id : $('#id').val()
    };
  },
  saveBook: function (event) {
    var title = $('#title').val(), 
        author = $('#author').val(),
        quantity = $('#quantity').val(),
        price = $('#price').val(),
        description = $('#description').val(),
        id = $('#id').val();
    if (id == '') {
        bkCollection.create({title: title,quantity: quantity,author: author,price: price,description: description});
  } else {
        //this.collection.add(model, {at: position});
        //var values = this.getInputValues();
        //_.each(values, function (value, key) {
        //  bkCollection.set(key, value);
        //});

         //how to update here

    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

for create working fine, how to update 
update url like :- localhost/test1/#edit/cd235c1e-a153-8039-aedb-67609b5bcdef

help to solve this

Comment: *"for create working fine"* - what is working fine..? and what exactly is not working..? *"how to update here"* - update what..? Your `saveBook` is creating model instead of `save()` while `addBook` is not creating anything... Since the code is confusing It's hard to understand unless you explain clearly

Comment: best way to use localstorage (create,edit, delete) any examples,

Comment: to update the model, find it and save it with new data... `model.save(newData)`. How to find it... I don't know. It is not clear what you're trying to do. Do you have many forms..? Do one form represent one model..? Or just one form to which a specific model data is loaded..? If so, how are you finding the model for that... Many things are not clear.